# Is there a way to get rid of the "activate Flash" button in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

In the past few weeks I got an "activate Flash" button after opening the browser and visiting a site with a flash application. Is there a way to allow flash on that site automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way (that I can think of) is to click on the lock icon at the beginning of the address bar and go to site settings. There, you can allow, block or ask first on several items (i.e. ads, pop-ups, java, flash, etc.)

Comment: Doesn't really work. I mean if I restart the browser, I have to set it again. I guess that is a bug, idk.

Comment: Not a bug, it's by design. Flash is being phased out and browsers are actively disabling it by default.